# Is there a way to go from a set of (F/D)FT values to FIR coefficients?

Tags: fft, audio, fourier, real-time, finite-impulse-response

I'm not yet well educated on the DSP subject, but I've initiated a project where I will do some audio filtering.
My intuition tells me that there is a link between the coefficients of a FIR filter and the response of the audio indicated by values of a fourier transform.

My question; is there a way to go from FFT data to FIR coefficients?
What about the other way around?

I apologize that I probably do not use the correct terms.
Thank you for any response :)

---

EDIT: I got a request to make this clearer, so here is some pseudo code of what I want to do given a stream of audio data:

```
fftdata = fft(stream)
soSomethingTo(fftdata) //for instance increase bass response
FIRcoef = translate(fftdata)
stream = fir(stream, FIRcoef)
```

So, this would analyze the stream and create a FIR that slightly modifies the fft response.

Comment: When you mention "values of a fourier transform", you mean fourier transform of what exactly? Could you give more detail to your question?

Comment: edits made, not really sure what I can do to make it clearer? Both an FT and a FIR operates on a signal / stream of discrete values. They would operate on a stream of PCM audio data.  :)

Comment: If you perform the filtering (such as increasing the bass response) directly in the frequency domain by modifying the FFT sample values, why don't you perform inverse FFT and obtain the stream directly from there?

Comment: I need the actual filter to be (close to) real time, so I will use a FIR to do the actual filtering. But I want to have a second process update the coefficients to perform some correction on the stream. The actual correction may be more bass, or less bass. I will end up with a FFTerror = FFT(wanted) - FFT(actual), now I need to convert the error to a set of FIR coefs, so I can do mean-squared error update of the current weights. At least this is my current thinking.

Comment: btw, thanks for your input bone, do you have some resource for DSP to recommend? Preferrably targeted at audio. I know math and programming so I'm scared for something theoretical, though an easy read is always appreciated :) Thanks again

Comment: First of all, be carefull with the size of the filter, if it is too long it may be faster to filter by FFT than to perform convolution. But yes your reasoning seems correct, I would just instead of transforming the error, directly antitransform the new FFT filter and get the new FIR coefficients from there. In terms of assembly instructions it will actually be faster to change the values that to perform addition of the error in time domain to your existing coefficients. As for Resources: The book by Oppenheim and Schafer is a good source.

Comment: "antitransform the new FFT filter and get the new FIR coefficients from there." this is exactly what I'm trying to figure out if is possible (and if so, then how). Just ordered the book [costs as much as the DSP devkit I ordered ^^], thanks

Comment: You are confusing two processes - one provides information of spectral content of a signal, the other filters the signal. In other words, if I understand correctly your goal - based on the FFT result you want to adopt the FIR filter coefficients. In your case it is a kind of low frequency band pass or a low pass filter. I assume that you want a real time self adapting process - you have two challenges - defining the filter in the frequency domain and than "calculate" or select the FIR filter. Hwo you decide the filter desired from the FFT?

Comment: I am not confusing the two processes ;) "based on the FFT result you want to adopt the FIR filter coefficients." It is exactly my question; if there is a known approach for this. Any idea? :)